# Back Button for UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiwebview, theos

Im attempting to create a left navigation button to send my webview back a page, but when trying to compile theos throws the following error :

property 'webView' not found on object of type 'DDRootViewController *'if ([self.webView canGoBack]) {

the code Im using is below, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

DDRootControllerView.m

```
#import "DDRootViewController.h"

@implementation DDRootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

        //Create UIWebView
            UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
            webView.delegate = self;
            [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dylanduff.github.io/WidgetStore/"]]];
            [self.view addSubview:webView];
            webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            //NSString *theTitle=[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
            self.title = @"Widget Store";

        //Create back button
            //self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addButtonTapped:)] autorelease];


}

- (void)updateBackButton {
    if ([self.webView canGoBack]) {
        if (!self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem) {
            [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
            UIBarButtonItem *backItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"<" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backWasClicked:)] autorelease];
            [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:backItem animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else {
        [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
        [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self updateBackButton];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self updateBackButton];
}

- (void)backWasClicked:(id)sender {
    if ([self.webView canGoBack]) {
        [self.webView goBack];
    }
}


@end
```

DDRootControllerView.m

```
@interface DDRootViewController : UIViewController
<UIWebViewDelegate> {}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

As You have taken local instance of `webView`, you can not access it out of the scope of `ViewDidLoad`. For accessing the instance of `webView` outside the `viewDidLoad` you need to take public property for that like this

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) UIWebView *webView
```

Now you need store webView object in the public property declared earlier so that you can use this property all over the class, your viewDidLoad method will look like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

     //Create UIWebView
            self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
            self.webView.delegate = self;
            [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dylanduff.github.io/WidgetStore/"]]];
            [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
            self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            //NSString *theTitle=[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
            self.title = @"Widget Store";

        //Create back button
            //self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addButtonTapped:)] autorelease];

}
```

Comment: The app compiles but the back button isn't visible :/

Comment: @DylanDuff You never call the updateBackButton method in viewDidLoad, so the back button is never created.

Comment: @DylanDuff You also don't need to use autorelease in your code. That's an artifact from the pre-ARC days where developers had to keep up with memory management themselves.

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidload you create **local** webView variable. Of course it is not visible from another method.

If you have property webView defined (as I can suggest from the code), use self.webView instead of UIWebView *webView in viewDidLoad method.